# Why does Tolkien barely mention the Ring in terms of Frodo's physical handling of it?

Tags: j-r-r-tolkien, the-lord-of-the-rings

As I'm approaching the end of The Two Towers, I'm increasingly frustrated by how, other than in the very beginning of the story in the first book, we never hear a single phrase such as:

> Frodo immediately sat up, looking around for Gollum, realizing that Sam was still sleeping next to him, reaching for the chain tucked away underneath his mithril mail, making sure that the Ring was still in his possession. With a sigh of relief, he woke Sam and...

You never see that kind of thing in the entire story so far. Not even when they first encounter Gollum in the wilderness. Not once. Tolkien seems to have thought of every little detail, but apparently never felt the need to add such small reminders of how important the Ring is and how worried Frodo is to miss it.

There are numerous times, besides all those sleepovers with Gollum freely roaming around them, when it would make perfect sense for Frodo to at least make sure that The One is still secure. Maybe it's implied, but it seems to me almost as if Frodo has entirely forgotten all about it at this point. Or stuffed it somewhere where he constantly feels it. I may have forgotten about it, but I don't know where exactly he keeps it, other than it being attached to a chain and supposedly in one of his pockets.

Just the fact that they sleep with this Ring-crazed creature, who clearly goes to any length to get his "Preccccious" back, is in itself very strange to me, but that he seems so incredibly careless and doesn't even make sure that it's still on him is just downright *bizarre*.

Other than the poetry, my biggest complaint about the book are the very elaborate and confusing descriptions of the surroundings. With all that description of their surroundings, it makes me constantly wish for more details about the hobbits themselves and what they are thinking and doing.

It sounds a bit weird to say it, but there are many scenes where I think I could have slightly improved them by simply mentioning that Frodo is reaching for the Ring or moving his hands in that direction while somebody is talking or acting suspicious. I expected this to happen regularly throughout the entire series.

Answer (score 3):

Allow me to look at your problem from a slightly different angle. It's what I like about books (as opposed to movies): a good book encourages you to continually 'visualize' what happens yourself and immerse yourself in the world of the book. This includes details which the author deemed not worthy of mentioning over and over again, such as Frodo's interactions with the Ring, or what they (or the other members of the fellowship) had for lunch each day.

Note that Frodo wears the chain (often? always?) on his neck, so it would not be easy to grasp it from him without noticing. Perhaps that's the reason he doesn't worry too much?

> When he had dressed, Frodo found that while he slept the Ring had been hung about his neck on a new chain, light but strong.
> *The Fellowship of the Ring - Many Meetings*

Comment: I would say that always, except that brief time it was beard by _someone else_.